# ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList when running JMH with gradle

Tags: gradle, jmh

I want to benchmark my application using JMH.
I am using JMH with gradle as build tool.
The github repository is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/aerospike-test).

But whenever I run the application `com.demo.aerospike.JMHAerospikeSpringData` I get below error.

```
$ gradle run

> Configure project :
Task :jmh Last added: null

> Task :run
JMHAerospikeSpringData is running ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.AbstractResourceReader.getReaders(AbstractResourceReader.java:98)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkList.find(BenchmarkList.java:122)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:256)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:206)
    at com.demo.aerospike.JMHAerospikeSpringData.main(JMHAerospikeSpringData.java:47)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 
'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried different solutions in other stackoverflow but couldn't help.

Any idea what I'm missing.

Comment: your repo link is dead. if it's fixed, could you share it?

Comment: @BingLi224 - I updated the repo.

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this problem by adding this dependency to my project:

```
testAnnotationProcessor "org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:$jmhVersion"
```

next to

```
testImplementation "org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:$jmhVersion"
```

Answer (score 3):

implementation 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:1.33'

annotationProcessor 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:1.33'

just like lombok

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. "just like lombok" ist not enough. And https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try running without gradle daemon:

```
gradle --stop
gradle --no-daemon jmh
```

Comment: Same result for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how is your project setup like because I can't find `com.demo.aerospike.JMHAerospikeSpringData` in your repo. Maybe you want to check this project out to get some ideas to try.

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/core-java-modules/core-java-collections-maps-3/src/main/java/com/baeldung/map/concurrenthashmap/MapPerformanceComparison.java